# Timer on Cpp for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I need the most simplest timer for my project on Cpp for Linux. 
It is enough two methods:

```
Timer t1;
t1.start();
....
t1.gettime()
```

It would be great if I included some header file and got a timer.

Comment: Maybe you should start coding then.Take a look at [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: @churill,  OK,  and what should I do if I need 2 timers?

Comment: `Timer t1; Timer t2;`?

Comment: @churill, yes's, but how to get Timer?

Comment: You have to code one, I guess. SO is no site were we write code for you for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you're not able to use std::chrono, you can use linux's [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since c++11 you may use std::chrono for getting timings:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono
- https://www.techiedelight.com/measure-elapsed-time-program-chrono-library/